# Show view controller when app is returning from background (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'd like to show a password prompt every time my app returns from the background (trust me, it makes sense, it's not annoying; it's similar to what 1Password does).

So **I need to show a certain ViewController every time the app enters the foreground** or **every 10 minutes**.

I tried a lot, but I don't seem to get it to work. For instance:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("called it")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("called it")
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("called it")
}
```

These methods simply don't get called on my device. Please note that the app is iOS 13 only. There was some change I don't understand (scenes?).

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of the **NotificationCenter**.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showThePasswordViewController), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

After adding this line of code, possibly in your main views **viewDidLoad()** method, you also need a function called **showThePasswordViewController()** or whatever you want to call it. Make sure to declare it like this in the same view as where you add the observer:

```
    @objc showThePasswordViewController() {
    //your code to present it
    }
```

Don't be discouraged by the "@objc", it does not mean you need to write in objective-C. Also remember that when you add the observer you write your function name in the parentheses after **#selector** without the parentheses like this at the end () as demonstrated above. Hope this helps, Hans.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your time and effort, I appreciate it. I'm amazed that this works – I tried it and it does. Thank you. (You forgot to add a "func" in your second statement, but that's okay ;) ).

Somehow, using the Notification Center for this feels like a hack. Is this the "official" way of doing this? Maybe someone else has another idea?

Comment: In an app that only supports iOS 13, `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` shouldn't ever be posted. You should only listen for and get the UIScene equivalent.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, that's what I was thinking about (that's why I mentioned iOS 13). Do you have an idea where I can find more documentation on this? Or could you help me?

Comment: Use NotificationCenter is not a hack. It is the correct way. That is how you should handle app/scene lifecycle events in a specific view controller or other class. Start with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes and follow the maze of related links to other guides. And watch the relevant videos from WWDC 2019.